# IE 9 has trouble loading HTML5 audio from Tomcat

Tags: html, url, tomcat, html5-audio, src

My HTML5 audio player, when running inside of IE9, has trouble playing audio files located on a server running Apache Tomcat. For example, it'll never load the file at this path:

http://www.siascend.com/repository/audios/1017_Q1.mp3

but happily plays the same file located @:

http://hirebrodie.com/demo/audio/1017_Q1.mp3

Either path works fine when the player runs in Chrome or Safari. Why wouldn't it work in Internet Explorer? Is this a known issue with the IE implementation of HTML5 audio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat by default specifies for a .mp3 extension the MIME type audio/x-mpeg.Changing this default to audio/mpeg solves the issue.In other words IE9 is NOT comfortable with audio/x-mpeg but accepts audio/mpeg as MIME type of a resource for an  tag.

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/iewebdevelopment/thread/b4f58d95-ac27-4a28-a4ae-86477ddfc74f

Comment: Changing the MIME type in the web.xml worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: Would you happen to know what MIME IE9 prefers for .m4a files?

Comment: To enable your web server to support the audio formats you need to ensure that the web server such as Apache can serve the appropriate file fomats – if some browsers get media errors, add the following mime types to the ‘.htaccess’ at the root web serving folder: AddType audio/mpeg mp3 AddType audio/mp4 m4a AddType audio/ogg ogg oga

Comment: For more info: http://crosstown.coolestguyplanettech.com/web-host/43-no-video-with-supported-format-and-mime-type-found