# Why doesn't the audio tag work in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-audio

Why is this code not working? In other browsers it plays without any problems but in IE I just get "Error: Unsupported audio type or invalid file path". Ive really tried everything but nothing works, except to force the browser to emulate an older version of IE

Heres the test code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Tack för Ert köp!</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='/phpstyles.css' />

</head>
<body>
<?php


                                echo("<audio id='testry' controls preload='auto' autoplay >");
                                echo("<source src='/1.mp3' />");
                                echo("<source src='1.mp3' />");
                                echo("<source src='1.mp3' />");
                                echo("<source src='/1.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' />");
                                echo("<source src='1.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' />");
                                echo("<source src='/1.mp3' type='audio/mp3' />");
                                echo("<source src='1.mp3' type='audio/mp3' />");

                                echo("Your browser does not support the audio tag.");
                                echo("</audio>");



?>
</body>
</html>
```

And heres my .htaccess

```
     # BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddType text/css .css
        AddType text/x-component .htc
        AddType application/x-javascript .js
        AddType application/javascript .js2
        AddType text/javascript .js3
        AddType text/x-js .js4
        AddType text/html .html .htm
        AddType text/richtext .rtf .rtx
        AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
        AddType text/plain .txt
        AddType text/xsd .xsd
        AddType text/xsl .xsl
        AddType text/xml .xml
        AddType video/asf .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx
        AddType video/avi .avi
        AddType image/bmp .bmp
        AddType application/java .class
        AddType video/divx .divx
        AddType application/msword .doc .docx
        AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
        AddType application/x-msdownload .exe
        AddType image/gif .gif
        AddType application/x-gzip .gz .gzip
        AddType image/x-icon .ico
        AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe
        AddType application/json .json
        AddType application/vnd.ms-access .mdb
        AddType audio/midi .mid .midi
        AddType video/quicktime .mov .qt
        AddType audio/mpeg .mp3 .m4a
        AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
        AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe
        AddType application/vnd.ms-project .mpp
        AddType application/x-font-otf .otf
        AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database .odb
        AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart .odc
        AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula .odf
        AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics .odg
        AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation .odp
        AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet .ods
        AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text .odt
        AddType audio/ogg .ogg
        AddType application/pdf .pdf
        AddType image/png .png
        AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint .pot .pps .ppt .pptx
        AddType audio/x-realaudio .ra .ram
        AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf
        AddType application/x-tar .tar
        AddType image/tiff .tif .tiff
        AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf .ttc
        AddType audio/wav .wav
        AddType audio/wma .wma
        AddType application/vnd.ms-write .wri
        AddType application/vnd.ms-excel .xla .xls .xlsx .xlt .xlw
        AddType application/zip .zip
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
        ExpiresByType text/x-component A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/javascript A31536000
        ExpiresByType text/javascript A31536000
        ExpiresByType text/x-js A31536000
        ExpiresByType text/html A3600
        ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
        ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A3600
        ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
        ExpiresByType text/xsd A3600
        ExpiresByType text/xsl A3600
        ExpiresByType text/xml A3600
        ExpiresByType video/asf A31536000
        ExpiresByType video/avi A31536000
        ExpiresByType image/bmp A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/java A31536000
        ExpiresByType video/divx A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/msword A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A31536000
        ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A31536000
        ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
        ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/json A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A31536000
        ExpiresByType audio/midi A31536000
        ExpiresByType video/quicktime A31536000
        ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A31536000
        ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31536000
        ExpiresByType video/mpeg A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A31536000
        ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/pdf A31536000
        ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A31536000
        ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A31536000
        ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/x-tar A31536000
        ExpiresByType image/tiff A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31536000
        ExpiresByType audio/wav A31536000
        ExpiresByType audio/wma A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/zip A31536000
    </IfModule>

    <FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|js|js2|js3|js4|CSS|HTC|JS|JS2|JS3|JS4)$">
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header set Pragma "public"
            Header append Cache-Control "public"
        </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|SVG|SVGZ|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header set Pragma "public"
            Header append Cache-Control "public"
        </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip|ASF|ASX|WAX|WMV|WMX|AVI|BMP|CLASS|DIVX|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|GIF|GZ|GZIP|ICO|JPG|JPEG|JPE|JSON|MDB|MID|MIDI|MOV|QT|MP3|M4A|MP4|M4V|MPEG|MPG|MPE|MPP|OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|PNG|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|RA|RAM|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TAR|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|WAV|WMA|WRI|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW|ZIP)$">
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header set Pragma "public"
            Header append Cache-Control "public"
        </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
    # END W3TC Browser Cache

Header unset ETag
FileETag None

# Hantera och redirecta användare till en gemensam error-sia
ErrorDocument 404 /psych/cgi-bin/error/error?404 

# BEGIN Turn ETags Off 
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
</ifModule>
FileETag None
# END Turn ETags Off 

# BEGIN Gzip Compression
     <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # force deflate for mangled headers
  # developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
      RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  # HTML, TXT, CSS, JavaScript, JSON, XML, HTC:
  <IfModule filter_module>
    FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/html
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/css
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/plain
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/x-component
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/javascript
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/json
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xhtml+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/rss+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/atom+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/svg+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/x-font-ttf
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $font/opentype
    FilterChain     COMPRESS
    FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule !mod_filter.c>
    #The following line is enough for .js and .css
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css
    # Legacy versions of Apache
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
    #The following lines are to avoid bugs with some browsers
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html 
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
        Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
# END Gzip Compression

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DefaultLanguage sv-SE

# Force “File Save As” Prompt
AddType application/octet-stream .avi .mpg .mov .pdf .xls .mp4 .rar
AddType application/octet-stream .mp3

<FilesMatch "\.(?i:mp3)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>

AddType audio/ogg ogg AddType audio/ogg oga AddType audio/wav wav AddType audio/mpeg mp3 AddType audio/mp4 mp4 AddType audio/mp4 mpa
```

Comment: Orly? Kinda frustrating when it should work but doesnt and noone here seems to know why, nor is it possible to google for it. But whatever then

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 <audio> tag do not work/play in IE10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631848/html5-audio-tag-do-not-work-play-in-ie10)